# Record voice in android getting error unfortunately your app stopped

Tags: android

I am new in android guys I was trying to record voice. the program run normally on the emulator put when I try to run it on the mobile it crash  getting unfortunately your app stopped

this is where the function that record exist (start)

```
final MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
private MediaController mediaController;

public void start() throws IOException {
String state = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if(!state.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))  {
    throw new IOException("SD Card is not mounted.  It is " + state + ".");
}

// make sure the directory we plan to store the recording in exists
File directory = new File(path).getParentFile();

if (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs()) {
  throw new IOException("Path to file could not be created.");
}


File path_file=new File(path);
if(path_file.exists())
{

    path_file.delete();
    Log.w("path_file", path_file.toString()); 

}


recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
Log.w("noooooo", path_file.toString());
recorder.setAudioChannels(1);
recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);

recorder.setOutputFile(path);
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();
start_time=System.currentTimeMillis() ;

}


public void stop() throws IOException {
recorder.stop();
recorder.reset();
recorder.release();
}
```

---

this is where i call it

```
public class VoiceRecorder extends Activity implements OnPreparedListener, MediaController.MediaPlayerControl{


AudioRecorder audio=new AudioRecorder(path);

private MediaController mediaController;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;


 private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

 private long elapsedTime;
 private final int REFRESH_RATE = 100;
 private boolean stopped = false;
 private Runnable startTimer = new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           if(!stopped){
           elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start_time;
           updateTimer(elapsedTime);
           mHandler.postDelayed(this,REFRESH_RATE);
        }

           }
    };



 long secs,mins,hrs;
 String seconds,minutes,hours,milliseconds;

  private void updateTimer (float time){
    secs = (long)(time/1000);
    mins = (long)((time/1000)/60);
    hrs = (long)(((time/1000)/60)/60);

    /* Convert the seconds to String
     * and format to ensure it has
     * a leading zero when required
     */
    secs = secs % 60;
    seconds=String.valueOf(secs);
    if(secs == 0){
        seconds = "00";
    }
    if(secs <10 && secs > 0){
        seconds = "0"+seconds;
    }

    /* Convert the minutes to String and format the String */

    mins = mins % 60;
    minutes=String.valueOf(mins);
    if(mins == 0){
        minutes = "00";
    }
    if(mins <10 && mins > 0){
        minutes = "0"+minutes;
    }

    /* Convert the hours to String and format the String */

    hours=String.valueOf(hrs);
    if(hrs == 0){
        hours = "00";
    }
    if(hrs <10 && hrs > 0){
        hours = "0"+hours;
    }

    /* Although we are not using milliseconds on the timer in this example
     * I included the code in the event that you wanted to include it on your own
     */
    milliseconds = String.valueOf((long)time);
    if(milliseconds.length()==2){
        milliseconds = "0"+milliseconds;
    }
    if(milliseconds.length()<=1){
        milliseconds = "00";
    }
    milliseconds = milliseconds.substring(milliseconds.length()-3, milliseconds.length()-2);

    /* Setting the timer text to the elapsed time */
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3)).setText(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
    //((TextView)findViewById(R.id.timerMs)).setText("." + milliseconds);
}

  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_voice_recorder);


     b1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {  
        public void onClick(View v)
            {
                //perform action
            try{

                b1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);//start
                b2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//stop
                b2.setEnabled(true);//stop
                b2.requestFocus();//stop

                audio.start();
                start_time=audio.start_time;
               // updateTextView();
              try{
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(startTimer);
                mHandler.postDelayed(startTimer, 0);
              }
              catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }




                catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
         });    

  }

 //--MediaPlayerControl methods--
  public void start() {
    mediaPlayer.start();
  }

  public void pause() {
    mediaPlayer.pause();
  }

  public int getDuration() {
    return mediaPlayer.getDuration();
  }

  public int getCurrentPosition() {
    return mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
  }

  public void seekTo(int i) {
    mediaPlayer.seekTo(i);
  }

  public boolean isPlaying() {
    return mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
  }

  public int getBufferPercentage() {
    return 0;
  }

  public boolean canPause() {
    return true;
  }

  public boolean canSeekBackward() {
    return true;
  }

  public boolean canSeekForward() {
    return true;
  }
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  @Override
  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
      Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared");
      mediaPlayer.start();
        mediaController.setMediaPlayer(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.main_audio_view));

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            mediaController.setEnabled(true);
            mediaController.show();
          }
        });
  }


 @Override
  protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mediaController.hide();
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.reset();
    mediaPlayer.release();
  }

 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
     super.onDestroy();
     mediaPlayer.release();
     mediaPlayer = null;
 }

 @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    //the MediaController will hide after 3 seconds - tap the screen to make it appear again
    mediaController.show();
    return false;
  }

 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        intent.setClassName("vodafone.voice", "vodafone.voice.AndroidListViewActivity");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }





 }
```

and this is the logcat:

```
05-23 12:46:18.028: E/AndroidRuntime(7389): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-23 12:46:18.028: E/AndroidRuntime(7389): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:    length=2; regionStart=-1; regionLength=1
05-23 12:46:18.028: E/AndroidRuntime(7389):     at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:593)
05-23 12:46:18.028: E/AndroidRuntime(7389):     at    java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1474)
05-23 12:46:18.028: E/AndroidRuntime(7389):     at vodafone.voice.VoiceRecorder.updateTimer(VoiceRecorder.java:109)
05-23 12:46:18.028: E/AndroidRuntime(7389):     at vodafone.voice.VoiceRecorder.access$3(VoiceRecorder.java:60)
05-23 12:46:18.028: E/AndroidRuntime(7389):     at vodafone.voice.VoiceRecorder$1.run(VoiceRecorder.java:48)
05-23 12:46:18.028: E/AndroidRuntime(7389):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:608)
05-23 12:46:18.028: E/AndroidRuntime(7389):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-23 12:46:18.028: E/AndroidRuntime(7389):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
05-23 12:46:18.028: E/AndroidRuntime(7389):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
05-23 12:46:18.028: E/AndroidRuntime(7389):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-23 12:46:18.028: E/AndroidRuntime(7389):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-23 12:46:18.028: E/AndroidRuntime(7389):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-23 12:46:18.028: E/AndroidRuntime(7389):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-23 12:46:18.028: E/AndroidRuntime(7389):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: it actually work one time and anther don't so it confuse me more

Comment: Can you post your stacktrace/logcat output when it crashes? That will make it a lot easier to help get to the bottom of your problem.

Comment: but it doesn't crash on the pc it only crash on the mobile

Comment: Enable USB Debugging in the Developer Options in the Settings menu on your phone, connect the phone to your PC and open the Logcat view in Eclipse.

Comment: oka thanks i will do that and copy the log here

Comment: @michael thanks i finally got the logcat from the mobile debugging

Answer (score 0):

Based on your logcat output the error seems to be in this piece of code:

```
if(milliseconds.length()<=1){
    milliseconds = "00";
}
milliseconds = milliseconds.substring(milliseconds.length()-3, milliseconds.length()-2);
```

With `milliseconds` set to `"00"` you'll get a `beginIndex` of `-1` (`milliseconds.length()-3`) for `substring()`, which causes a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.